# Minecraft Bukkit Server

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I have created my own Craft Bukkit Minecraft server, and have everything almost set up but have run into a problem. You see, I wish for the server to automatically say something like this every 45 seconds or so:

[Server] Remember to follow the rules! (ETC.)

But I am not sure how to do it. I think I'll require a script, but I have no idea how I'd go about writing it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Good starting point: https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_Tutorial

Comment: There are already plugins for that... Plugins like *AutoMessage* do exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Write a plugin and start a `BukkitRunnable` in `onEnable()` to run every 900 ticks (for 45 seconds) and call `getServer().broadcastMessage("hello world")` within it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not programming related, but instead is related to the running of a program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make your own plugin you can do a scheduler task every X time and Bukkit.broadcastMessage.

Example:

```java
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage("[Server] This is the message.");
        }
    }.runTaskTimer(this, 20, 20*60*10); // 20*60*10 = 10 minutes
}
```

But if you want a already coded plugin you can download it from spigotmc.org
https://www.spigotmc.org/search/31904533/?q=automessage&t=resource_update&o=relevance